# Need help in generating scripts in java language in Selenium IDE

Tags: java, selenium

i am trying to record actions performed in the Firefox browser using Selenium IDE. I observed that for recorded scripts, the default language in source tab is HTML. As i wanted to have scripts in java, i got into Options->format in menu bar but i do not see Java listed in there. I could only see HTML, Ruby, python and C#. Could you please help me in generating/converting scripts in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do not have (or have but deactivated) Selenium Java plugin installed for your IDE.

1. If you're using Selenium 1.x version, then go to `Selenium IDE->Options->Options` and check Enable experimental features
2. Alternatively, try installing the latest stable version from [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/2.4.0/selenium-ide-2.4.0.xpi)

You can also check what's installed from `Selenium IDE->Options->Options->Plugins` tab

[image]

**EDIT:**

For recording options in Java, please see the below settings in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked, i have selected java formatters in the java plugins page, now i am able to export recorded test cases in java language. But still i see that recorded script are in HTML format.

Comment: I am using Selenium IDE 2.4.0 *. I tried changing in clipboard format as java but still the script is in HTLM. Could you please help me solve this one too.

Comment: @Srekk I have added the screenshot for that too, basically I just get formats option within Options menu and if I select Java, it throws and initial warning of being an experimental feature and then carries on with the recording

Comment: Thanks PopoFibo. I did that.